# covariance between continuous and discrete random variables

Tags: distributions, covariance

Let $Y \sim Ber(p)$ and $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. 
I want to compute $Cov(Y,X)$ and joint distribution of $(Y,X)$. Are there any useful reference? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the population covariance or the sample covariance?

Comment: There isn't just *one* possible joint distribution. The simplest that comes to mind is simply the product of the two distributions, which makes the probabilities of the two quantities independent and therefore $\mathrm{cov}(Y,X)=0$.

Comment: I'm considering population covariance.

Comment: $cov(X,Y) = E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}\times \{0,1\}}(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)dF_{X,Y}(x,y)$. $F_{X,Y}=F_X(x)F_Y(y)C_{X,Y}(F_X(x),F_Y(y))$. $C_{X,Y}(F_X(x),F_Y(y))$ is the copula between $X$ and $Y$. For a discrete distribution, the copula isn't unique, so I assume (but concede that I'm not certain) that this kind of mixed distribution does not have a unique copula, which puts you in an interesting situation. I think that you have omitted some details about the problem, because we can't even surmise what the copula is if we only know the marginal distributions but not the joint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One well-known possibility for what you're looking for is the [Point-biserial correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dear all,  Many thanks. Very useful!

Comment: @user0131 So please upvote my answer, I definitely need some points! :)

Comment: @user0131 THANKS!